# How to show an activity indicator bar while waiting for response from a server?

Tags: ios, ios7, activity-indicator

all! First, I've seen all such kind of questions but still confused, that is why I am asking.
I have a button "translate". When I press the button it send request to the server and gets response  back. So while waiting for answer I need activity indicator bar be showing. I tried some several codes, but nothing works. Can anybody help me with that? Here is my code. My activity indicator is activityInd.

```
-(IBAction)translate
{
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[self textView1] text], @"SourceText",@"8a^{F4v", @"CheckCode",@"0",@"TranslateDirection",@"1",@"SubjectBase", nil];
NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *result=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fake.com/notRealUrl"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:result];

    NSURLResponse *response=nil;

    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];

    NSString *str=theReply;
    str= [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(51, str.length - 51 - 2)];

    NSString *result2=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r\\n" withString:@""];
    _textView.text=result2;
}
```

THANKS ALL! I FOUND A WAY HOT TO USE ASYNCHRONOUS REQUEST.
NOW EVERYTHING WORKS FINE.

Answer (score 2):

You are making synchronous request. So it will be executed on main thread. That will make your main thread busy and your UI will not be changed during that time. Make the communication request asynchronous and your UI will be updated with activity view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   //set ivar in your view controller
   UIActivityIndicatorView * spinner;

   //alloc init it  in the viewdidload
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(self.center.x, 150)];
    spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
    [spinner setColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Before requesting add the following code:

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
```

On completion:

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in UI only on main thread.

```
-(void)translate
{
//maybe your app is running on main thread so Start Spinner in main thread.
UIActivityIndicatorView * spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[spinner setCenter:self.view.center];
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];

// Create this temporary block.
[self callService:^(NSData *data, BOOL success)
{
    /*--- When you get response execute code in main thread and stop spinner. ---*/
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
    ^{
        // now app is in main thread so stop animate.
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        if (success)
        {
            NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
            //do what you want.

        }
    });
}];
}

-(void)callService:(void(^)(NSData *data,BOOL success))block
{
//we are calling Synchronous service in background thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"", @"SourceText",@"8a^{F4v", @"CheckCode",@"0",@"TranslateDirection",@"1",@"SubjectBase", nil];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *result=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://fake.com/notRealUrl"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:result];

    NSURLResponse *response=nil;

    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    // When we got response we check that we got data or not . if we get data then calling this block again.
    if (POSTReply)
        block(POSTReply,YES);
    else
        block(nil,NO);
});
}
```

Maybe this will help you.